# How do I parse every string while comparing two excel spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-formula, vba

**Good evening,**

I'm attempting to compare two excel spreadsheets by using the IF and MATCH functions as follows:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(fromADP!$C2,fromSMS!$A$2:$A$4792,0)),"No match found",fromADP!$C2)
```

I have two worksheets (fromADP and fromSMS).  I'm trying to compare the two worksheets to find out which records in the **fromADP** worksheet appear in the **fromSMS** worksheet.  The MATCH function allows me only three options for the match_type arguement.  I'm using 0, although I'm not sure I understand exactly how the other two options work.  I tried them though without desirable results.

When I use match_type 0 I only get one match - but this is an exact match (as I would expect).  My problem is, some of the records do in fact exist in both worksheets but there are minor differences (for example, "Tony's" vs. "Tonny's" or "Jimmy's Trucking, LLC" vs. "Jimmy's Trucking").

So I'm wondering, is there another way to do this or could there be - perhaps - a vbscript that would parse each string in my lookup_value?  This way, I can find those records where there might be slight differences.

I'm afraid I may simply have to pull out my ruler and pencil and start combing through the spreadsheets, line-by-line.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is neither VBA nor VBScript code in your question. Questions about Excel formulas are better asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.  I will move the question there.  Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi all,**

Thanks to the solution offer [**here**](https://superuser.com/questions/437387/comparing-similar-text-strings-in-excel), I was able to use the [**Fuzzy Lookup Addin for Excel**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) to accomplish this task.  Thus, my question is answered and my issue resolved.